# How to copy windows files to ubuntu, from Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, mount, windows-8, files, transfer

So long story short, I can't access windows 8.1 atm and would like to transfer my files (aka school notes) from windows to Ubuntu so I don't lose them.  I am running Ubuntu 12.04 as a dualboot on a single hdd.
This is what I get when I go to the terminal and type lsblk.

```
alek@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk
[sudo] password for alek: 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 698.7G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   102M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  19.5G  0 part 
└─sda3   8:3    0   679G  0 part /host
sr0     11:0    1   3.3G  0 rom  /media/alek/UDF Volume
loop0    7:0    0  19.3G  0 loop /
alek@ubuntu:~$
```

I'm not sure how to get to my files...

```
alek@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT
[sudo] password for alek: 
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT
sda           698.7G 
├─sda1 vfat     102M 
├─sda2 ntfs    19.5G 
└─sda3 ntfs     679G /host
sr0    udf      3.3G /media/alek/UDF Volume
loop0  ext4    19.3G /
```

Comment: Hi friend, can you update your information with this "sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT". That way we can know which partition is the one holding Windows by the TYPE column.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the Windows partition is `sda1`, you can simply open the Nautilus file manager and navigate to it from the Device menu on the left or, if you want to mount the unit using the terminal you can do it 2 ways that will force Windows 8 to be mounted but be warned that anything hibernated will be lost:

```
sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt -o remove_hiberfile
```

or

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

They will remove the hibernation flag and any hibernated data (The hibernate file) from Windows. This way, Ubuntu will open your Windows partition.

Seeing the new information I would umount the partition:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda3
```

If it does not unmount, you can do the following:

```
sudo fuser -km /dev/sda3
```

Then try to mount it on a correct place like `/mnt` or `/media/alek/PARTITION`, or even opening it with Nautilus. Just in case, any "I can't opened this because it is hibernating" can be fixed with the `remove_hiberfile` option mentioned above.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that my windows partition is sda3...does that change anything?

Comment: @AlekBerthelet: Yes, if you're sure, just replace `/dev/sd*` with the path to your Windows partition. It seems weird though because `sda3` is already mounted at `/host` according to the output of `lsblk`.

Comment: @Luis: Why do you suggest to mount `sda1`, if you assume the Windows partition is `sda2`? Otherwise +1.

Comment: This is what I get: Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.

Comment: That shows if it is actually mounted already or if the partition is detected in hibernation mode. If the latter applies, then doing the steps mentioned above will let you remove the hibernation phase and be able to mount and retrieve the files. Please let us know how it went. For the correct partition, I am giving an example, with the information provided I do not know which partition it is. I simply used sda1 as the example, but it could have been any before you found out which..

Comment: It appears to be a wubi install not a true dual boot - `/host` would be the host Windows system, I think.

Comment: Ahh ok I see. Did not know. Thanks for the knowledge steeldriver.